# How to do Loadbalancing with BDR

Tags: postgresql, high-availability, pgpool

I'm planning to use BDR (by 2ndQuadrant) in my Database Environment to achieve a multi master cluster for my PostgreSQL Database. Since i would have many nodes in my cluster and all able to read & write i want to make the cluster transparent to its clients and also balance the load between all available nodes.

Is it a good idea to combine pgpool and a BDR Cluster or is there a better way to distribute the load?